# wxPython: GridBagSizer: Iterating over rows and columns of a gridbagsizer

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Is there a way to iterate through the Children of a wx.GridBagSizer in row/column order?

I have noticed that I can perform a GetChildren() on a sizer but I could not find documentation in the API which says how these children actually map to rows or columns.
There are two methods:

```
GetEffectiveRowsCount()
GetEffectiveColsCount()
```

But I am not sure how to use these to iterate through the children.
I have included a template below:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.inspection


class MyRegion(wx.Frame):
    I = 0

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="My Region")
        gridSizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

        gridSizer.Add(self.CreateStaticBoxSizer(4), pos=(0,0), span=(4,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        gridSizer.Add(self.CreateStaticBoxSizer(4), pos=(4,0), span=(4,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        gridSizer.Add(self.CreateStaticBoxSizer(4), pos=(0,1), span=(4,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        gridSizer.Add(self.CreateStaticBoxSizer(8), pos=(0,2), span=(7,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        gridSizer.Add(self.CreateStaticBoxSizer(6), pos=(0,3), span=(6,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(gridSizer)
        for item in gridSizer.Children:
            for r in range(0, gridSizer.GetEffectiveRowsCount()):
                print(item.GetSize())

    def CreateStaticBoxSizer(self, x=4):
        box = wx.StaticBox(parent=self, label="StaticBox::" + str(MyRegion.I))
        MyRegion.I += 1
        sz = wx.StaticBoxSizer(orient=wx.VERTICAL, box=box)
        for i in range(x):
            sz.Add(wx.StaticText(parent=sz.GetStaticBox(),
                                 label="This window is a child of the staticbox"))
        return sz


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyRegion(None)
    frame.Show()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items returned from `GetChildren()` are simply a collection of the items added to the sizer, in the order they were added.  In Classic the items are `wx.SizerItem` objects so you can't get any information about position or spanning from them.  However in Phoenix they are `wx.GBSizerItem` objects so you can use `GetPos` to find their location in the grid if desired.

To iterate over the items in grid order you can use `FindItemAtPosition` which returns a `wx.GBSizerItem` or `None` if there is no item at the requested position.  So something like this should give you what you are looking for:

```
for row in gridSizer.GetEffectiveRowsCount():
    for col in gridSizer.GetEffectiveColsCount():
        item = gridSizer.FindItemAtPosition((row, col))
        if item is not None:
            print(item.GetSize())
```